# jQuery Swapping Elements Contents Gives Type F error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Based on my other thread here I have updated the JS Fiddle [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/rmatakajr/FN7Xx)

```
     $(".drop-container").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    //accept: "#mykeys ul li",
    accept:"#mykeys ul li, .drop-container li",
    //connectWith: ".drop-container",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
         var cid=ui.draggable.attr("id");
         var from_id=ui.draggable.parent().attr('id');       
         if(typeof from_id != 'undefined'){

            var editor = $('#'+cid);  //put your ids here
            var viewer = $('#'+from_id);

            editorContent = editor.clone();
            viewerContent = viewer.clone();

            editor.replaceWith(viewerContent);
            viewer.replaceWith(editorContent);

         }
         $(this).empty();
         //append the draggable onto this
        $(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);
    },
    out: function( event, ui ) {
        var oid=$(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        console.log('dragged out '+oid);
        var from= $(this).closest(".drop-container").attr("id");
        //console.log('from '+ from);               
    }
   });
```

What I'm trying to do is swap the contents out when
we drag between containers. For the life of me I cannot
get this to work right. Hoping you can help.

When you go to the fiddle code you will see that you 
can drag from the list and drop on the containers
then you can drag and drop between the containers

What I'm trying to do here is if there is current content
in the container you are dropping into it will swap
it out with the content you are dropping in almost
like a sortable would work. But I can't figure out
how to attach a sortable to the structure I have

Comment: What is "Type F error"? :)

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/x9YRXrlN - I dunno but all im trying to do is get the elements to swap objects..between the containers because in the UL structure im building I cannot get sortable to work right

Comment: Yes, it says that `f` variable is `undefined`, a TypeError.

Comment: Yes I know, but thats being thrown by jquery.ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked & updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxJhk/) to a working version.

Changes:

- Added ID's to the `.drop-container` spans
- `:drop` callback: changed `accept: "#mykeys ul li",` to `accept: "#mykeys ul li, .drop-container li",` since the dropped elements are not in `#mykeys` anymore
- `:drop` callback: added `source_element` & `existing_element` so we can get source & target and swap the items in the `.tree` list